# In R, differences in coefficients between single-level and mixed-effect quantile regression

Tags: r, mixed-model, quantile-regression

I am using the *lqmm* package in R to estimate a mixed-effect quantile regression for the first time in an analysis of clustered data (individuals clustered within care providers). I am struggling to understand why estimates of the fixed effects in a quantile regression change when a random effect is introduced, which I will illustrate using the *sleep* dataset.

```
library(lqmm)
library(quantreg)
library(lme4)


# Read in 'sleep' dataset
data("sleep")

# Display data
sleep

   extra group ID
1    0.7     1  1
2   -1.6     1  2
3   -0.2     1  3
4   -1.2     1  4
5   -0.1     1  5
6    3.4     1  6
7    3.7     1  7
8    0.8     1  8
9    0.0     1  9
10   2.0     1 10
11   1.9     2  1
12   0.8     2  2
13   1.1     2  3
14   0.1     2  4
15  -0.1     2  5
16   4.4     2  6
17   5.5     2  7
18   1.6     2  8
19   4.6     2  9
20   3.4     2 10
```

In the sleep dataset, 10 individuals (ID) are given a drug on two occasions (group) and their increase in hours of sleep is measured (extra). The mean and median for *extra* is 1.54 and 0.95, respectively.

```
> # Summarise 'extra' overall, and by group
> summary(sleep$extra)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 -1.600  -0.025   0.950   1.540   3.400   5.500
```

Fitting a null linear model (lm) and then a null mixed-effect linear model (lmer) with a random effect on group, the estimated intercept is equal to the overall mean of 1.54.

```
# Fit a null linear model
lm(extra ~ 1, data = sleep)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)  
       1.54  

# Fit a null linear model with a random effect for group
# Note: the estimated intercept is identical between the two models
lmer(extra ~ 1 + (1|group), data = sleep)

Number of obs: 20, groups:  group, 2
Fixed Effects:
(Intercept)  
       1.54
```

This is not true when fitting a null quantile regression model to estimate the median (rq) and then extending this to a mixed-effect model (lqmm), however. The estimated intercepts are quite different between the two models.

```
# Fit a null quantile regression at the median
rq(extra ~ 1, data = sleep, tau = 0.5)

Call:
rq(formula = extra ~ 1, tau = 0.5, data = sleep)

Coefficients:
(Intercept) 
        0.8 

Degrees of freedom: 20 total; 19 residual

# Fit a null quantile regression at the median with a random effect for group
# Note: the estimated intercept is not identical between the two models
lqmm(fixed = extra ~ 1, random = ~ 1, group = group, data = sleep, tau = 0.5)

Call: lqmm(fixed = extra ~ 1, random = ~1, group = group, tau = 0.5, 
    data = sleep)

Quantile 0.5 

Fixed effects:
(Intercept)  
      1.555  

Covariance matrix of the random effects:
(Intercept) 
     0.5484 

Residual scale parameter: 0.7788 (standard deviation 2.203)
Log-likelihood: -43.63 

Number of observations: 20 
Number of groups: 2
```

In the single-level model, the estimated intercept is 0.80, which I can understand as ordering the data by *extra*, the 10th/20th individual has an *extra* value of 0.80. But I do not understand how to interpret the estimated intercept from the mixed-effect model.

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.